# Moving TFS 2010 application to another server

Tags: tfs, tfs-2010

I have a TFS 2010 application installed on server1.  I have the data tier on server2.  We are going to get rid of the server1.  I want to install the TFS application on Server2 (same server as data tier).  First of all, which configuration option do I pick during the install?  Do I have to bring my server1 down before installing application on the data tier server2?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find all the information you need at MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404879.aspx